# Return to quote by link?

Tags: checkout, quote

Is it possible to have a link which leads to **a quote / cart?** I want to be able to give a link to somebody ***who will in return complete the checkout process for that quote / cart***.

Comment: Please mention magento version?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for you but fortunately in terms of security Magento does not provide a way to access a specific cart directly by link.

The only link you can use is the login link for carts that have been created by logged in customers. Once logged in they'll be able to retrieve their cart by accessing the cart page.

For not logged in customers you can use the cart page directly and if their session has not expired they'll be able to access their cart.